# Android Activity XML resource identifier missing

Tags: android, xml, build

When I attempt to run my app and the Gradle Build is running, I get the following error:

```
No resource identifier found at attribute 'context' in package 'com.protonmail.fabian.schneider.aim'
```

(in the start activity)
(When double clicking on the error it takes me to the RelativeLayout Tag. But there are no errors in the file;
When I double click on the error in the same file in the debug folder, all the URLs are red and therefore probably the error...)

It worked fine the last weeks, but three days ago it stopped working, when I reordered the Elements on the activity.

I tried cleaning and building, restarting android studio. I also tried to change the URLs in xmlns:android,app,tools (because I found that when researching) - but non of it helped.

If it helps: here is the output from the Gradle Console:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:clean
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2421Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72421Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2421Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72421Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2421Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2421Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2421Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2421Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2421Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42421Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2421Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource identifier found for attribute \u0027context\u0027 in package \u0027com.protonmail.fabian.schneider.aim\u0027","sources":[{"file":"/home/faebl/Programming/apps/android/AIM/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_aim_start.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
/home/faebl/Programming/apps/android/AIM/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/layout/activity_aim_start.xml:2: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'context' in package 'com.protonmail.fabian.schneider.aim'



 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.695 secs
```

Can you please recommend some ways to resolve that issue?

Here is the XML in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.protonmail.fabian.schneider.aim"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.protonmail.fabian.schneider.aim.AIM_start">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AIM OS"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#0a0a53"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="Analysis of Interplanetary Magnetic-Field Data" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start AIM"
        android:id="@+id/start_AIM"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_x="112dp"
        android:layout_y="122dp"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom_rect"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Stop AIM"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/stop_AIM"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_x="148dp"
        android:layout_y="226dp"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/start_AIM"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/start_AIM"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/start_AIM"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom_rect"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_output"
        android:layout_x="139dp"
        android:layout_y="372dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/statusView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/statusView"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
        android:layout_x="138dp"
        android:layout_y="435dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stop_AIM"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_actualConfig"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <Button
        android:text="..."
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom_round"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: whats you application package name  ? is it `com.protonmail.fabian.schneider.aim` ?

Comment: once try with `clean` & `build`

Comment: @user1140237 I tried clean and build and it didn't work out...
Error comes when cleaning...
yes 'com.protonmail.fabian.schneider.aim' is my package name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally resolved the error by trial an error.

I don't really have an explanation for it but it did work.

I deleted the lines with xmlns:tools and tools:context as they were not needed anywhere later in the xml.
after deleting them, I cleaned and rebuilt the project and it works again.

Hope it helps anyone.
(if anyone has an idea to why it helped, please leave a comment :) )